# Expected value given pdf $\frac{1}{x^2}$ for $x \in 1$ to $\infty$

Tags: probability

Given the probability density function of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ for $x$ from $1$ to $\infty$.

The expected value is defined as $\int_1^\infty x f(x) \,dx= \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}\, dx = \ln(\infty) - \ln(1) = \infty$.

Is the argument above correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.  This variable has infinite expected value.

Comment: https://pranj.al/blog/Math/2012/03/26/infinite-expected-value-and-the-st-petersburg-paradox/